# Error messsage not working 100% Discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I have expanded my bot with a music bot commands. Everything works except 1 thing. When the bot joins the voice channel and the user types !play (url) it should play the music. It does that. But when the user forgets to put a url or a wrong url i want to send a error message. When it's empty it works, but when it's not valid it does not send a message.

So it goes somewhere wrong in the @play.error. it performs the last elif but not the first if statement. Someone knows why?

```
  @commands.command()
  async def play(self,ctx,url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)

  @play.error
  async def play_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please make sure it's a valid youtube url.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please enter a youtube url.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the URL given to `ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)` is invalid,
`youtube_dl` throws an Exception `youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError` (I think).

But in your error catcher, you only look for `BadArgument, MissingRequiredArgument`.

I would try adding another: to `@play.error` and Catch the other errors you might be missing.

```py
@play.error
  async def play_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please make sure it's a valid youtube url.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please enter a youtube URL.")
    else:
        print(f"Unknowen Error: {repr(error)}")  # If you want to send the error to discord just replace print with await ctx.send()
```